# Abp Tenant creation not working. AbpAuthorizationException at CreateStaticRoles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, aspnetboilerplate

After update to Abp 2.3 my tenant creation is not working anymore.

The exception is been throwing when the roles are created:

```
//TenantAppService.cs

//We are working entities of new tenant, so changing tenant filter
            using (CurrentUnitOfWork.SetTenantId(tenant.Id))
            {
                //Create static roles for new tenant
                CheckErrors(await _roleManager.CreateStaticRoles(tenant.Id)); <-- Here
```

The exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'Abp.Authorization.AbpAuthorizationException' in 
mscorlib.dll

Additional information: [At least one of these permissions must be granted]
```

I didn't change the TenantAppService that came from Module Zero, but if I remove the AbpAuthorize from class it works.

```
    [AbpAuthorize(PermissionNames.Pages_Tenants)] //If removed works
    public class TenantAppService : SeducaAppServiceBase, ITenantAppService
    {
    ...
```

Tks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was AbpCache.

What I need to do is restart the app (cleaning everything) or call the api method (api/AbpCache/ClearAll)

reference: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/aspnetboilerplate/issues/573

It's solves all my problems with permissions

Answer (score 0):

The user who is calling this method has to be granted permission with `PermissionNames.Pages_Tenants`.

Comment: The user has the permission, I checked at DB. In fact, if it had not, it could not even reach the call of the CreateStaticRoles method.